# Render React Component based on React-Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to render a specific component inside of another component based on **React**, **React-Router v4**, and **Redux**  in my main 'panel' wrapped in a fixed header and sidebar component.

For example when I select an item from the sidebar, I to render the `Detail` panel and and load the details based on the id, like: `<Route path='/item/:id' component={ItemDetail} />`

[image: Outline navigating React-Router]

routes.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { RouteHandler, Switch, Route, DefaultRoute } from 'react-router';
    import App from './containers/App';
    import Login from './containers/Login';
    import LobbyDetail from './components/LobbyDetail';
    export default (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    );
```

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import auth from '../actions/auth';
import Sidebar from '../Components/Sidebar'

class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
    };

    /**
     * 
     */
    render() {
        const { ... } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {* I WANT TO RENDER DYNAMIC COMPONENT HERE *}
                </div>
                <Sidebar currentUser={currentUser}
                    logout={logout}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

index.js (basically main app):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/store.js';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';

const syncHistoryWithStore = (store, history) => {
  const { routing } = store.getState();
  if (routing && routing.location) {
    history.replace(routing.location);
  }
};

const initialState = {};
const routerHistory = createMemoryHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState, routerHistory);
syncHistoryWithStore(store, routerHistory);

const rootElement = document.querySelector(document.currentScript.getAttribute('data-container'));

const render = () => {

  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={routerHistory}>
          {routes}
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    rootElement
  );
}

render();

if (module.hot) { module.hot.accept(render); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is parameterized routing. Make a `<Route/>` like the following: `<Route path='/item/:id' component={ MyComponent } />`.

Now in `MyComponent` you can use the value of `props.match.params.id` to conditionally render, or if you're trying to load async data based on the value of `:id`; You can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method and dispatch an action based on the value of `this.props.match.params.id`.

Note: `<Link to='/item/some-item'/>` will set the value of `match.params.id` to `'some-item'`.

Comment: where do I place the new `<Route/>` element? Also how do I `render it inside the rest of the `<div>` in my `App` component?

Comment: You put the `<Route/>` element where you want the component to render. Put the the `<Link/>` in your sidebar.

Comment: ok, I think I understand now (didn't realize `<Route/>` also rendered! w/ `<Link to={`/item/${item.id}`}>`, the "`" doesn't render here ([docs](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html)) I'm getting an error _Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function_

Comment: Please refer to this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) provided in the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). This should help you out.